# laravel search from two table in same controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two table which is a club_member and club_membership. The club_membership store the year of the club renewal. The club_member just store the basic info of the club. Here is the model of them.

ClubMember.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\OptimisticLocking;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class ClubMember extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use OptimisticLocking;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getLocalizedNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return \LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()=='zh-Hant'?$this->name_tc:$this->name_en;
    }

    public function getLocalizedCompanyNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return \LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()=='zh-Hant'?$this->company_name_tc:$this->company_name_en;
    }

    public function memberships() {
        return $this->hasMany(ClubMembership::class, 'club_member_id');
    }

    public function latest_membership() {
        return $this->hasOne(ClubMembership::class, 'club_member_id')->orderByDesc('id');
    }

    public function scopePreloadValues($query, $excludeInactive = false){
        $query = $query->select(
            'id as id',
            'username',
            'code',
            'name_tc',
            'name_en',
            'company_name_tc',
            'company_name_en',
            'category',
            'ci_br_num',
            'ci_br_attachment',
            'tel',
            'fax',
            'email',
            'website',
            'address_tc',
            'address_en',
            'contact_1_name',
            'contact_1_title',
            'contact_2_name',
            'contact_2_title',
            'attachment',
            'submission_date',
            'deleted_at'
        );
        if (!$excludeInactive)
            $query = $query->withTrashed();
        return $query->orderBy('deleted_at')->orderBy('id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

ClubMembership.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\OptimisticLocking;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class ClubMembership extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use OptimisticLocking;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function payment(){
        return $this->hasOne(Payment::class, 'club_membership_id');
    }

    public function scopePreloadValues($query, $excludeInactive = false){
        $query = $query->select(
            'id as id',
            'year',
            'code',
            'effective_date',
            'expiry_date',
            'deleted_at'
        );
        if (!$excludeInactive)
            $query = $query->withTrashed();
        return $query->orderBy('deleted_at')->orderBy('id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    }

    public function getStatusAttribute() {
        return $this->expiry_date >= Carbon::today() ? __('common.active') : __('common.expired');
    }
}
```

So, I would like to use the laravel eloquent way to join this two table. When I want search the year of entry, I need to first search the record in club_membership table in ascending order and get the first record. Then I get the club_member.id in club_membership table and search in the club_member table. Finally I show all the details of the club_member in the view.

ClubMemberSearchController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel\ClubMember;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ClubMembership;
use App\Models\SystemCode;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ClubMember;

class ClubMemberSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $variables['club_member_type'] = SystemCode::PreloadValues('club_member_type');

        $query = ClubMember::query();

        $query_year = ClubMembership::query();

        if ($request->has('name') && $request->get('name')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('name_en','like','%'.$request->get('name').'%')
                ->orWhere('name_tc','like','%'.$request->get('name').'%')
                ->orWhere('company_name_en','like','%'.$request->get('name').'%')
                ->orWhere('company_name_tc','like','%'.$request->get('name').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('code') && $request->get('code')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('code','like','%'.$request->get('code').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('email') && $request->get('email')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('email','like','%'.$request->get('email').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('tel') && $request->get('tel')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('tel','like','%'.$request->get('tel').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('fax') && $request->get('fax')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('fax','like','%'.$request->get('fax').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('year_of_entry') && $request->get('year_of_entry')!=null)
        {
            $query_year = $query_year->where('year_of_entry','like','%'.$request->get('year_of_entry').'%');
        }

        if ($request->has('category') && $request->get('category')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->where('category', '=', $request->get('category'));
        }

        if ($request->has('is_active') && $request->get('is_active')!=null && $request->get('is_active')!=0)
        {
            $query = $query->with('latest_membership.payment')->where('expiry_date', '>', now());
        }

        if ($request->has('sortOrder') && $request->get('sortOrder')!=null && $request->has('sortBy') && $request->get('sortBy')!=null)
        {
            $query = $query->orderBy($request->get('sortBy'),$request->get('sortOrder'));
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $query->orderByDesc('id');
        }

        $query = $query->with('latest_membership.payment');

        $items = $query->paginate();

        return view('panel.club_member.search', [
            'items' => $items,
            'variables' => $variables,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I know how to build the query in same table by Eloquent ORM. How can I search the join table result by Eloquent ORM? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried ... with(‘memberships.year_of_...?